# how to render epub file in react js sent from Spring Boot backend?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, epub

I am trying to render an epub file in react using ReactReader sent from Spring Boot backend in Json field as Base64 format. The code is not working, file is not being rendered in the front end.
I would have pasted the code i am getting an error from Stack Overflow.
Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.